# Calculating Birth Rate with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an `age` and `gender` `columns` in a `data frame` I want to examine the birth rate with respect to the information below

"we should be able to say how many children were born over the past year as a
fraction of the number of women aged 25-29. Determine this number, and express it as
“births per 100,000”.

and death rate with respect to the elderly people age comparations between 65-70 and 70-75. Could you help me to write a python code how can I do that?

```
birth_woman = (df["Gender"] == "Female")
birth_woman_age = (df["Age"] > 30)
birth_rate = birth_woman_age < 35
birth_rate.count()


birth_woman2 = (df["Gender"] == "Female")
birth_woman_age2 = (df["Age"] > 25)
birth_rate2 = birth_woman_age2 < 30
birth_rate2
```

Then I will divide each other could you check the code it returns all the observation numbers

Comment: The second line, birth_woman_age, gets a pandas Series of women over 30. The third line should get an error. You might try typing these in one at a time into a Python console to see how these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
birth_woman = df[(df["Gender"] == "Female") &
                  (df["Age"] > 30) &
                  (df["Age"] < 35)]
```

Comment: Also, you should rename the question to something like :  Pandas dataframe how to apply multiple conditions